# plotting between two curved lines

Tags: matlab, graph, matlab-figure

I have data where the X(time), Y1 (Median values), Y2(25th percentile) and Y3(75th percentile). Now i want to plot all these in the same plot, and shade the area between the median curve and upper quartile curve and again shade the area between median curve and lower quartile curve.
Is there some easy way to do this?

I  tried the option
    xx = [X,X];
    yy = [Y1,Y2];
    fill(xx,yy,'b');

.. But I am not happy with the above code as it does not give me the plot that I am looking for.
Please could someone help me.!!
Many thanks
SSR

Comment: The FEX is always a good place to start searching for [stuff like this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?term=tag%3A%22confidence+interval%22).

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
x = 0:.01:1;
y1 = 5+sin(2*pi*x);
y2 = y1-1;
y3 = y1+1; %// example values
fill([x x(end:-1:1)],[y3 y1(end:-1:1)],[.6 .6 .6]) %// light grey
hold on
fill([x x(end:-1:1)],[y2 y1(end:-1:1)],[.4 .4 .4]) %// dark grey
```

[image]

Comment: yes, this is the kind of plot i am looking for, but unfortunately when i use the same code as above to plot for my data then I do not get the expected results. What I get is the area under the median curve completely shaded and the area under upper quartile curve shaded.I want shading only between  the two curved lines..

Comment: Post a mininal example to reproduce your problem Without that it's hard to know what's wrong